# Iis possible to rewrite those string put the part of string starting with "# " above the string itself?

Tags: awk

Simple and fast question.

I have this

```
awk -f file            # awk use file as input
awk '/word/' file      # awk show me word
awk '/32$/' text       # all words with 32..
```

I want this

```
# awk use file as input
awk -f file       


# awk show me word                                              
awk '/word/' file      


# all words with 32..                                         
awk '/32$/' text
```

Is possible to do this maybe using awk? Also other commands are welcome (perl, sed, python..)

Comment: I can't make heads or tails what the "start with # over"  in the title means

Comment: Its far from clear what you are trying to ask here, perhaps you could give examples of input and output you want.

Comment: I have put the input, maybe the title was a little strange, I have corrected it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ awk -F '[[:space:]]+#' '{print "#" $2 ORS $1 ORS}' file
# awk use file as input
awk -f file

# awk show me word
awk '/word/' file

# all words with 32..
awk '/32$/' text
```

That only works if you only have 1 `#` preceded by spaces on each line of input like in the sample input/output you provided, though. If that's not the case in your real data then edit your question to provide more truly representative sample input/output including, for example, cases with `#`s preceded by spaces in your awk code and/or within the comments, e.g.:

```
awk '/foo # bar/' file          # lines with # before bar
```

and tell us the algorithm by which such cases, especially `#`s within comments, should be handled.

Answer (score 1):

With `perl`:

```
perl -i -lpe 's/(.*\S)\s+(#.*)/\2\n\1\n\n/' your-file
```

That moves the part after the right-most occurrence of a `#` following at least one whitespace character following a non-whitespace character.

With `-i`, the file is edited `i`n-place.